# Combine two where queries in ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to create an ecto query that returns a result when both where queries are met.  When I run the app, I get the error `function nil.title/0 is undefined or private`. Is this because I don't have the query right? I want an AND on the two where.

```
def next_prod do
  Post |> where(postStatus: "published") |> where(next_prod: "yes") |> Repo.one()
end
```

*SQL query*

You'll see there is a record that should match the ecto query.

```
iex(1)> Codsonline.Repo.query("SELECT * FROM posts")
[debug] QUERY OK db=3.0ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT * FROM posts []
{:ok,
 %Postgrex.Result{columns: ["id", "title", "snippet", "body", "slug", "mainImg",
   "thumbImg", "postStatus", "showStatus", "inserted_at", "updated_at",
   "next_prod"], command: :select, connection_id: 13732, num_rows: 1,
  rows: [[8, "Blackadder Goes Forth",
    "“Blackadder Goes Forth ” is the fourth and final part of the Blackadder series . A theatrical Dramatisation inspired by the TV episodes. Follow the Wit and Sarcasm of Captain BlackAdder  in Oscar Wilde language.",
    "27th January – 03rd February 2018\r\nPlayhouse Theatre, Cheltenham\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nEpisodes:\r\n‘Corporal Punishment‘ (Episode 2)\r\n‘Private Plane‘ (Episode 4)\r\n‘Goodbyeee‘ (Episode 6)\r\n\r\nDirected by Nick Tobias & Liz White\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nCast List:\r\n\r\nCaptain Edmund Blackadder – Chris Hannant\r\nPrivate S Baldrick – Matt Wilson\r\nLt. Hon. George Colthurst St Barleigh – UNCAST\r\nGeneral Sir Anthony Cecil Hogmanay Melchett – Jason Blackburn\r\nCaptain Kevin Darling – Jack Homer\r\nSquadron Commander the Lord Flashheart – Michael Fay\r\nField Marshall Sir Douglas Haig – Will Browne\r\nBaron Von Richthoven – Robert Barton-Ancliffe\r\nBob ‘Bobbie’ Parkhurst – Sarah Bottomley\r\n\r\nEnsemble – Ben Wilson (Sergeant Jones), Oliver Chapman (Gerhardt), Michael Sheldrick (Perkins), Steve Scott, Matthew Morris",
    "blackadder-goes-forth", ".", ".", "published", "Future",
    {{2017, 11, 18}, {22, 36, 19, 408441}},
    {{2017, 11, 18}, {23, 3, 42, 816258}}, "Yes"]]}}
```

Comment: You want `next_prod = "yes" AND next_prod = "no"`? That'll not match anything. Your syntax is correct btw. That error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: ha copy paste error.  Just corrected the string in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is not from this line of code. Your code is fine and the two clauses will be AND'd by Ecto. The error means that you tried to call `nil.title` somewhere.

```
iex(1)> nil.title
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function nil.title/0 is undefined or private
    nil.title()
```

I'm guessing you called `.title` on the return value of this function and you don't actually have a record that matches those two conditions in the database. You should use `Repo.one!` if you want to ensure that a record exists. Or if you want to handle the case where the record doesn't exist, use `if`:

```
if record = Thing.next_prod do
  # record exists
else
  # it doesn't
end
```

Comment: Fairly sure the record exists, as I can see it in the index of `posts = Blog.list_posts()` I can see one record that would be true for both of those where clauses.

Comment: Can you add the output of that command and the SQL query you get in the log when you run this function to the question?

Comment: The field in your database is "Yes" while in the query you're using "yes". Can you try making them the same case?

Comment: Damn. That was it.  Case mismatch.